# Ubuntu Immediate client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I could ssh into other machines fine, but a broken pipe msg shows up immediately when trying into ssh into machine A, including ssh into itself.

```bash
ssh machine_A@localhost
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

So far, i tested the solutions seen in the posts below as well as a couple google posts. Not sure what the problem is. hoping someone may have seen a similar issue or know a direction that I could continue to investigate in.

- [ssh connection "client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe" or "Connection reset by <IP> port 22"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602518/ssh-connection-client-loop-send-disconnect-broken-pipe-or-connection-reset)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624585/client-loop-send-disconnect-broken-pipe-while-running-long-experiments-with

Edit: added output of `ssh -vvv user@localhost` after requesting password

```bash
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@localhost's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
Authenticated to localhost ([127.0.0.1]:22) using "password".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug3: send packet: type 1
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

Comment: You could try running the SSH command with "-v" to get more information about the error. **Example:** ssh -v root@localhost

Comment: I would start by checking the syslogs on the server host to see if the sshd process on that end is logging anything for these connections. Aside from that, try running ssh with the "-vv" flag to print debugging info, then [edit] your question to include the debug output. It should show what ssh was doing when the connection failed.

Comment: thank you for the advice =] I edited the question to include the debug output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this eventually got solved this by purging the openssh-server with the steps below. my previous attempts were simply doing a --reinstall, which afaik, isn't as thorough.

Steps below:

```bash
# backup config
sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.bak

# reinstall
sudo apt-get --purge remove openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-server

# restart sshd
sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
```